# Can't authenticate using wsHttpBinding with ClientCredentialsType=Username

Tags: wcf, wshttpbinding

I am new to WCF and now really lost with this problem...
I want my WCF Service to authenticate incoming request using the username and password provided by client.

**Relevant parts of Web.Config looks like this:**

```
<endpoint name="wsBinding" 
          address="" 
          binding="wsHttpBinding" 
          contract="ServiceLib.IBooking" 
          bindingConfiguration="myWSSettings"
          />
```

And...

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myWSSettings">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication
          userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
          customUserNamePasswordValidatorType= "ServiceLib.MyCustomUserNameValidator, ServiceLib" />
      </serviceCredentials>

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

MyCustomUserNameValidator is just a temporary validator which simply throws Exception if username is not equal to password.

Client program (a console app) is doing this:

```
        BookingClient client = new BookingClient("wsBinding");
        Passenger passenger = new Passenger();

        // ../

        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "SomeUserName";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "WrongPassword";

        // ...
        // ...

        // NOTE: Following should throw My SecurityException Since username and
        // Password are not equal
        bool confirmed = client.IsTicketConfirmed(passenger);
```

**This is the error I get:**

**The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM,Basic**

Would really appreciate any help! I have spent tons of time trying to figure this out but in vain.

Thanks
Sandeep

**Note:--------**

1. I am using GoDaddy to host my WCF Service. Security mode = "Message" cannot be used there due to partial trust.
2. SSL certificate is correctly installed.

Answer (score 1):

You must change security mode to TransportWithMessageCredential :

```
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SafeServiceConf">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
```

You will found a good sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59927/WCF-Service-over-HTTPS-with-custom-username-and-pa).

Comment: Where to set username / password?